# Is it okay for us to split said and that by inserting a clause in between in the following sentence?

Tags: grammar

Is it okay for us to split "said" and "that" by inserting a clause in between in the following sentence?

> In Africa I met a boy, who was crying as if his heart would break, said, when I spoke to him, that he was hungry because he had had no food for two days.

Comment: The split works. But something needs a fix: *In Africa, I met a boy who, crying as if his heart would break, said when I spoke to him that he was hungry because he had had no food for two days*. On the other hand, why do we need "when I spoke to him"? When else would he have told me that?

Comment: The problem is that *a boy* cannot be the object of *met* and subject of *said* at the same time.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Aren’t you contradicting your stance on subjectless relative clauses? “I met a boy said that you ate all the pies” for example?

Comment: It seems a bit like the grammar of “There was a farmer had a dog…”

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore.: I'm not sure I *had* a "stance on subjectless relative clauses" before posting my previous comment. Perhaps you're referring to [my comment example](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/52526/adverbs-prepositions-nouns-home-and-about#comment98494_52535) *I saw a man [**who was**] about my height* (from over 10 years ago). In casual conversation, I have no problem with "eliding" ***who*** (*and* perhaps the actual verb ***was*** in my example, but we certainly can't discard ***said*** in yours! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers Not the verb *said*.just the subject *who*, which is what's happening in OP's example.

Comment: Marcus - your ***when I spoke to him*** is syntactically no different to a single-word adverbial element, such as *The boy said **quietly / later / yesterday** that he was hungry* (the position of adverbs and prepositions can be quite flexible in English).

Answer (score 1):

The split would work fine if that is the author's voice for the piece.
I would remove the comma after "boy."
"said" may be better as "who said."

"In Africa I met a boy who was crying as if his heart would break, who said, when I spoke to him, that he was hungry because he had had no food for two days."